# How to filter a Django model to display only the logged-in user's data?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-filters

Trying to solve this for a week now. How do I filter my model to display only the data assigned to the specific logged-in user? My views.py code below is not working---it's not telling forms.py what it needs to do to accomplish this. I get the error 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'option1'.

It does filter effectively in the template---but I need to use the RadioSelect widget (defined in forms.py) in order to display specific choices that the specific logged-in user must choose from (and I don't think I can---or should---code that in the template).

views.py

```
class VoteView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Result
    form_class = VotingForm
    template_name = 'users/vote_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, 
                     **kwargs):
        context = 
              super().get_context_data 
              (**kwargs)
        context['Result'] = 
            Result.objects.all()
        context['user_specific'] = 
            Result.objects.filter 
       (custom_user=self.request.user)
       return context

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs=super(). 
               get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs.update({'results': 
       Result.objects.
               filter(custom_user=
               self.request.user)})
       return kwargs

 * Added following post method, but 
   get " KeyError 'results' " error

   def post(self, request, *args, 
           **kwargs):
       form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.custom_user = 
                 self.kwargs
        instance.save()
    return redirect('users:home')


   def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('users:home')
```

forms.py

```
class VotingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         choices = [('1', Result.decision.option1),
                    ('2', Result.decision.option2)]
         self.fields['vote'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, label="Choices", widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ['decision', 'vote']
```

models.py (if  needed)

```
class Result(models.Model):
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision) * Decision 
                                             contains 
                                             decisions and 
                                             their choices 
                                (like 'option1', 'option2')
    vote = models.CharField()
    vote_eligible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

vote_form.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for item in user_specific %}

    {% if item.vote_eligible ==True %}    
       <div class="field-bold">
            Decision
       </div>
       <p>{{ item.decision }}</p>

       <div class="field-bold">
       {{ form.vote|as_crispy_field }}
       </div>

    <div class="btn-container">
        <div class="btn-grp">
           <input type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-submit" 
            value="Vote"/>
           <a href="{% url 
            'users:home' %}" 
            class="btn 
            btn-cancel">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% endfor %}

    {% if not user_specific %}
        <p>There are currently no 
         decisions awaiting your vote. 
        </p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```py
choices = [('1', Result.decision.option1),
           ('2', Result.decision.option2)]
```

What you're doing here is setting choices according to model fields. You're not using their values. Their values are tied to particular instance of the `Result` model.

Usually, this problem requires that you know which instances of the `Result` model will be used for the options. I normally pass it in the form kwargs like this:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         results = kwargs.pop('results')
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         # Now we're using a model INSTANCE, not the model itself
         # Also, you don't need to use the number for a key value. Makes
         # it a bit easier.
         choices = []
         for result in results.all():
             choices.append((result.decision.option1, result.decision.option1))
             choices.append((result.decision.option2, result.decision.option2))
         self.fields['vote'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, label="Choices", widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Then in the views.py add `get_form_kwargs` to initialize the kwargs for your form:

```py
def get_form_kwargs():
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'results': Result.objects.filter(custom_user=self.request.user)})

    return kwargs
```

Comment: Thanks @vinkomlacic. We're almost there. I get "TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"...But your code does work for just one argument (like 'option1') when I eliminated 'option2' from the append line. How can I append both arguments to the model instance? I tried creating choices_1, choices_2 and appending one argument to each---but got a different error.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the syntax. This should clear it (note the double parenthesis). From there you can eliminate whichever line you need

Comment: Thanks @vinkomlacic! That worked and I learned new things.

Comment: @vinkomlacic...Am I missing a step for the user's vote to post? The user's vote is not posting (or rather updating) their record in the model Result. Do I need to add code in forms.py or maybe modify the post method in views.py?

Comment: What is the HTTP response when posting - 200 or 302? Also, do you see any errors? Maybe you can add `vote_form.html` so we can get a clearer picture.

Comment: Thanks @vinkomlacic. Nothing happens. When "Vote" is clicked, the page refreshes---but it doesn't redirect to the get_success_url, and in the Admin Portal the vote field for the logged in user's record in Result is empty... I did add vote_form.html (see above). In addition, I just tried to edit the base class's post method (see above in views.py), but I get the error "KeyError 'results' "...Wasn't even sure I should include that post method code at all, since the user is not creating a new record but rather just editing a record that had already been created for them?

Comment: If the page refreshes, but you don't get redirected, it means that you have errors in the form. If you're not displaying these errors, you won't see them in the HTML. However, they are present in the `form.errors` form dict.

Comment: Also, there is no need to edit the `post` method. If you need to do things like this it is better to override the `form_valid` method to do things before or after saving the form.

Comment: And your HTML is a bit confusing. Are you trying to display multiple forms? From the code above and your description I was assuming you're trying to **create** a new `Result` instance.

Comment: I wonder what the form error could be. PyCharm gives me a green checkmark on the form...Here's how it will work: An administrator will first create a record in Result for each user, populating the record with just the user's email address and the decision and choices (assigned to that user). Then, the user will update that record (that corresponds to them--using vote_form.html) with their vote. I haven't yet developed the form that the administrator will use to initially create the record. Should I develop that form first, and then allow the user to update that form using the UpdateView class?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be easier. Also, from what I understand you don't need the `CreateView` in this case above, but `UpdateView`. Another thing is that you're trying to update multiple `Result` instances which means that you will need a **formset**, not a form. It is possible to use formsets with CBVs such as `UpdateView` but you need to override some extra methods. I think using a `modelformset_factory` is the way to go.

Comment: I will point you [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets) to the resources for formsets (please read it all), and for any other questions and problems that you might have, I suggest opening a new question, of course, after researching it yourself (feel free to tag me in comment so I see it).